# Formatting Strings with two parameters in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, stringwithformat

I have got a float value which is supposed to have a certain number of decimal places. The number of decimal places is stored in a variable.

Here is the line of code:

```
self.numberTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.%df",result, [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"decimalPlaces"]];
```

My problem is that I do not know how to combine the %f and %d specifiers in the right way.
Any ideas?

Thank for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can replace a field width or precision by an asterisk (`*`) and it will then pick up the value from the parameter list.

```
int width = 5;
int precision = 2;
double value = 3.1415926;
NSString* formattedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%*.*f", width, precision, value];
```

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html

Consider also using an [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  It has the advantage of being Internationalisation aware.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to do this in 2 stages

first create the formatted string with the desired number of decimal points:

```
NSString *format = [NSSString stringWithFormat:@"%%.%if", numberOfPlaces];
```

%% is an escaped percentage so the only part that will be replaced in the format will be %i, i.e. numberOfPlaces = 2 will give format = @"%.2f"

Then you use that format string to create the end result

```
NSString *valueString = [NSString stringWithFormat:format, myLongFloat];
```